# How to cycle through images with button clicks using services in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to cycle through images with button clicks, so far, but not in my code that I posted. I tried a routing approach, which did not work, so I deleted my code. If anyone could show, or provide any suggestions on how to tackle this problem.

My goal is, whenever the users click the next or prev button, the URL should update, thus changing to the next image.

For example, the URL would be http://localhost:4200/image/8 and, if the user hits the back or forward button, the URL would update to http://localhost:4200/image/7 or http://localhost:4200/image/9 respectively, thus changing the image on the screen.

Below, you will find the snippets of my HTML code, `graph.service.ts` file, where I have an array of all the images, and my `metric.component.ts` file, where I attempt to get the `ids` of the graphs and display them.

```html
<div class = "row">
    <button class="previous round">&#8249;</button>
    <div [ngStyle] = "{'background-image': 'url('+ graph.url +')'}" class ="img-container">
    </div>
    <button class="next round">&#8250;</button>
</div>
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GraphService {

  constructor() { }
  
  getGraph(id: number){
    return GRAPHS.slice(0).find(graph => graph.id == id)
  }

}

const GRAPHS = [
  {id: 1, catergory: "Popularity", url: "assets/img/pgraph.jpg" },
  {id: 2, catergory: "releasefrequency", url: "assets/img/rqgraph.jpg" },
  {id: 3, catergory: "lmd", url: "assets/img/lmd.jpg" },
  {id: 5, catergory: "last discuss overflow", url: "assets/img/ldof.png" },
  {id: 6, catergory: "performance", url: "assets/img/performance.jpg" },
  {id: 7, catergory: "security", url: "assets/img/security.jpg" },
  {id: 8, catergory: "responsetime", url: "assets/img/responsetime.png" },
  {id: 9, catergory: "closingtime", url: "assets/img/isueclosing.png" }
];
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { ImageService } from '../metric-details/shared/image.service';
import { LibraryService } from '../library.service';
import { Library } from '../library';
import { GraphService } from '../graph.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-metric-view',
  templateUrl: './metric-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./metric-view.component.css']
})
export class MetricViewComponent implements OnInit {
image: any
graph: any
library: Library;
visibleImages: any[] = [];


  constructor(private imageService: ImageService, private libraryService:LibraryService, private graphService:GraphService, private location: Location, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLibrary();

    this.image = this.imageService.getImages(
      +this.route.snapshot.params['id'])

    this.graph = this.graphService.getGraph(
      +this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
  }

  getLibrary(): void{
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.libraryService.getLibrary(id)
      .subscribe(library => this.library = library);
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to store the activeImageIndex in a variable, set it to 0 by default. And then you change the activeImageIndex by using the (click) button output: `(click)="activeImageIndex++"` for example. Then if you have a graphs array, you can select the active graph by using: `graphs[activeImageIndex].url`

Comment: @enf0rcer I'm not quite sure I really understand your solution. Could you elaborate some more? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must subscribe to the params changes and update the `activeId` in your component. You cannot rely on `snapshot` value, because the params will change after the component is created and the router will not recreate the component if only the params changed. So your `ngOnInit` and `constructor` will only run once.

Here is an reactive example. I'm not using a separate service for the images, but feel free to extract whatever you want into the separate service.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <div> {{ activeImage }} </div>
  <button (click)="prev()">Prev</button>
  <button (click)="next()">Next</button>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ImagesComponent  {
  images = [
    'first image',
    'second image',
    'third image'
  ]

  activeId = 0;

  get activeImage() {
    return this.images[this.activeId];
  }

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      map((params) => params.get('id') || 0), 
      map(n => Number(n))
    ).subscribe(id => this.activeId = id);
  }

  next() {
    const next = this.activeId + 1 >= this.images.length - 1 ? this.images.length -1 : this.activeId + 1;

    this.router.navigate([next])
  }

  prev() {
    const prev = this.activeId - 1 < 0 ? 0 : this.activeId - 1;

    this.router.navigate([prev])
  }
}
```

The example assumes the following route configuration:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', redirectTo:'0', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: ':id', component: ImagesComponent }
])
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/image-cycle-activated-route)

Comment: Why does it only work with that route configuration? The code in the ngOnInit I'm not really sure what it does.

Comment: I've provided the route configuration to show that the `:id` param exists.  It will work with any route configurations that have the `:id` param.

Comment: Oh ok, so essentially I could modify it to fit my own route configuration of 'image/:id'?

Comment: if your `metric-view` component has the `:id` param, the code will work just the same.

Comment: Thank you.. my metric-view component has "image/:id" as the param

Comment: It will work :) Can you accept my answer? Creating the code sample took a little bit of time, and I think it is the right solution.

Comment: Yeah Thanks again! It does work with the path as ":id" but when I try to use "image/:id" it does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168194/discussion-between-tomasz-kula-and-pennyboy).